# How to stop the random first item selected in dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here, I wrote code for the user to choose the name of the table as an item from the drop-down list, then the table information is displayed in the following table template, but when I run it selects the first item from the drop-down list, even if I try to choose another, knowing that I put the first item disabled for selection.

**aspx page**

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" runat="server"
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**aspx.cs page**

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string ddlQuery = "SELECT name from sys.tables ";
    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(ddlQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(ddlQuery, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dt);
    ddl1.DataSource = dt;
    ddl1.DataTextField = "name";
    ddl1.DataValueField = "name";
    ddl1.DataBind();
    ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Section", string.Empty));
    ddl1.Items[0].Selected = false;
    ddl1.Items[0].Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
    conn.Close();

    DataTable table1 = GetData();

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        GetData();
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<table>");

        html.Append("<tr>");

        html.Append("<th>Service ID </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Service Name </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Simple Service Description </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Service Description </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Service Image </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Service Time </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Service Price </th>");
        html.Append("<th>Action </th>");

        html.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in table1.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }
        html.Append("</table>");

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal
        {
             Text = html.ToString()
        });
    }
}

DataTable GetData()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();

        string SectionName = ddl1.SelectedValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SectionName))
        {
            return new DataTable(); // or return an empty DataTable
        }
        else
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM  ["+ SectionName +"]";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adpt1 = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    adpt1.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    using (DataTable dt1 = new DataTable())
                    {
                        adpt1.Fill(dt1);
                        return dt1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `GetData()` twice, but the second time you throw away the return value. Drop the second call. Also the whole method body should be within `if (!this.IsPostBack)` (it makes no sense to execute the query then).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show how you populate the `ddl1.Items`. It looks like you only give it the first value and then disabled it and set it shouldn't be the one selected.

But since there isn't any other value the dropdown list can select instead of the first one, it has to select it.

Comment: Ok, how to assign values ​​to other dropdownlist items since the items are getting from the database

Comment: @RenadMohammed get the items from the database and add them to the ddl1.Items.